# How to get an image from an API response with content type "mime: image/jpg" in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, mime-types

I did a request to an API and obtain characters from an image. I want to put those characters into a 'jpg' file to be able to visualize the image. The content-type is 'mime: image/jpg' and the data is the following one (it's not the complete one because it would be too much):

```
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
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick bit of research indicates `/9j/` is a *magic number* likely indicating the binary representation of a JPEG file that's been Base64-encoded. ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38783884/jpeg-image-in-base64-format)).

Thus it should be possible to use the `base64` module in Python to generate the file you describe:

```
import base64
jpg_b64_string_data = "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"
image_data = base64.decodestring(jpg_b64_string_data)
f = open("image.jpg", "w")
f.write(image_data)
f.close()
```